# RESTAngular - PUT, Create new record

Tags: angularjs, rest, put, restangular

I have created a service with RESTAngular in order to ease my communication with my REST API. Let's say that i have an object `Person`.
Here is my service:

```
myApp.factory('RESTService', [ 'Restangular', function (Restangular) {
    var restAngular = Restangular.withConfig(function (Configurer) {
        Configurer.setBaseUrl('/myAPI/');
    });
    var service = {};
    service.Person= restAngular.service('person');
    return service;
}]);
```

I can successfully:

GET the list of `Person`

```
RESTService.Person.getList().then(function (response) {
   $scope.persons = response.plain();
})
```

GET one `Person`

```
RESTService.Person.one(id).get().then(function (response) {
    $scope.person = response.plain();
})
```

POST (Update) `Person`

```
RESTService.Person.post($scope.person).then(
                function (successResponse) {
                      // success stuff
                },
                function (errorResponse) {
                    console.log("fail", errorResponse.status);
                }
            )
```

But i can't do `PUT` (create a new record). Now let's say i have a form and the form's data is being kept in `$scope.formData`. I want to do make a `PUT` request passing the object contained in `$scope.formData` to my API. How do i do that?

---

**EDIT**: For clarification my API is REST, so i do

- `GET  - /myAPI/person` to get the list of all the persons
- `GET  - /myAPI/person/123` to get the person with id=123
- `POST - /myAPI/person/123` to update the person with id=123
- `PUT  - /myAPI/person` to insert a new person in my database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a person for which you don't know the id yet, your API should accept a `POST` on `myAPI/person`. I assume Restangular expects that.

You don't want to accept a `PUT`, because the request is not idempotent. This is part of the semantics of a `PUT` and you want to adhere to that.

This SO question explores this in more detail: [PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)